# ImportError: cannot import name 'QhullError' from 'scipy.spatial' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py)

Tags: python, docker, scipy, kaggle

I am using Kaggle to do some work.

For some reason this line:
`import imgaug as aug # data augmentation`
caused this error :
`ImportError: cannot import name 'QhullError' from 'scipy.spatial' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py)`

`scipy` is `1.11.1` and `scikit-image` is `0.21.0`

I picked the >Always use the latest environment.
[Here is the code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ngguangrenryan/tensorflow-to-pytorch-conversion-a-practice), it is a conversion project to pytorch from the [original tensorflow](https://www.kaggle.com/code/aakashnain/beating-everything-with-depthwise-convolution)

I tried `!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall install scipy` but to no avail.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 10
      7 import h5py
      8 import shutil
---> 10 import imgaug as aug # data augmentation
     11 import numpy as np # linear algebra
     12 import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imgaug/__init__.py:9
      4 # this contains some deprecated classes/functions pointing to the new
      5 # classes/functions, hence always place the other imports below this so that
      6 # the deprecated stuff gets overwritten as much as possible
      7 from imgaug.imgaug import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
----> 9 import imgaug.augmentables as augmentables
     10 from imgaug.augmentables import *
     11 import imgaug.augmenters as augmenters

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imgaug/augmentables/__init__.py:8
      6 from imgaug.augmentables.lines import *
      7 from imgaug.augmentables.heatmaps import *
----> 8 from imgaug.augmentables.segmaps import *
      9 from imgaug.augmentables.batches import *

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imgaug/augmentables/segmaps.py:12
      9 import six.moves as sm
     11 from .. import imgaug as ia
---> 12 from ..augmenters import blend as blendlib
     13 from .base import IAugmentable
     16 @ia.deprecated(alt_func="SegmentationMapsOnImage",
     17                comment="(Note the plural 'Maps' instead of old 'Map'.)")
     18 def SegmentationMapOnImage(*args, **kwargs):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imgaug/augmenters/__init__.py:21
     19 import imgaug.augmenters.pillike  # use via: iaa.pillike.*
     20 from imgaug.augmenters.pooling import *
---> 21 from imgaug.augmenters.segmentation import *
     22 from imgaug.augmenters.size import *
     23 from imgaug.augmenters.weather import *

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imgaug/augmenters/segmentation.py:21
     17 import numpy as np
     18 # use skimage.segmentation instead `from skimage import segmentation` here,
     19 # because otherwise unittest seems to mix up imgaug.augmenters.segmentation
     20 # with skimage.segmentation for whatever reason
---> 21 import skimage.segmentation
     22 import skimage.measure
     23 import six

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/segmentation/__init__.py:7
      5 from .slic_superpixels import slic
      6 from ._quickshift import quickshift
----> 7 from .boundaries import find_boundaries, mark_boundaries
      8 from ._clear_border import clear_border
      9 from ._join import join_segmentations, relabel_sequential

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/segmentation/boundaries.py:5
      2 from scipy import ndimage as ndi
      4 from .._shared.utils import _supported_float_type
----> 5 from ..morphology import dilation, erosion, square
      6 from ..util import img_as_float, view_as_windows
      7 from ..color import gray2rgb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/morphology/__init__.py:12
     10 from ..measure._label import label
     11 from ._skeletonize import medial_axis, skeletonize, skeletonize_3d, thin
---> 12 from .convex_hull import convex_hull_image, convex_hull_object
     13 from .grayreconstruct import reconstruction
     14 from .misc import remove_small_holes, remove_small_objects

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/skimage/morphology/convex_hull.py:4
      2 from itertools import product
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull, QhullError
      5 from ..measure.pnpoly import grid_points_in_poly
      6 from ._convex_hull import possible_hull
```

Comment: What version of `scipy` are you using?  Also, that `pip install ...` command has the word `install` twice.  That's an error.

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?

Comment: it is `scipy-1.11.1`

Comment: Are you sure it's 1.11.1?  How did you get that version number?

Comment: `!pip show scipy`

Comment: `pip` may not be linked to the correct version of python.  Show us this output `!pip --version`

Comment: `pip 23.1.2 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)`

Answer (score 2):

I also just stumbled accross this issue. I am not sure where it comes from but I managed to hack it by running the following code snippet before importing anything from `scipy`:

```
from scipy.spatial.qhull import QhullError
from scipy import spatial
spatial.QhullError = QhullError
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).